# How to find electric flux through a surface due a point charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

So, I'm trying to solve this problem for my assignment,

A point of charge, Q = 3 nC, is located at the origin of a cartesian coordinate system. What flux crosses the portion of the z=2 m plane for which -4 $\le$ x $\le$ 4 m and -4 $\le$ y $\le$ 4 m

[image]

I'm thinking this question can be solved by using this equation
$$\Psi = \oint \mathbf{D} \cdot d\mathbf{S}$$
because the limits of the integration are already known from the problem

but I don't understand how I can get the D of this question. Am I using the wrong formula?
can someone clear this out for me? Thanks.

Comment: There are two things that need sorting out.  Are you looking for electric field flux or displacement field flux?   By context I think you are looking for displacement field flux.  If you can't think of a way to calculate ${\bf D}$ directly, perhaps you can find it another way.  You would have to make the reasonable assumption that the problem lies in a vacuum.

Comment: Say you considered vacuum. Then the equation would be $\Psi = \oint \vec{E}\cdot \vec{da}$. Assume small area $dxdy$ on the plane. This area points in the $z$ direction. Calculate $\vec{E}$ for some general point $(x, y, z_0)$. Evaluate the flux $\oint Eda\cos\theta$ involving double integrals with the limits for $x$ and $y$ given.

Comment: If it were the $z=4$ m plane it would be so easy!

Comment: Related : [What is the electric field flux through the base of a cube from a point charge infinitesimally close to a vertex?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/278628/what-is-the-electric-field-flux-through-the-base-of-a-cube-from-a-point-charge-i/351672#351672).

Answer (score 1):

Consider some point $(x,y)$ on the surface of interest. The distance of that point to the origin is $R=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+2^2}$. The angle of elevation for the vector that connects the point $(x, y)$ to the origin is $\theta=\cos^{-1}(\frac{2}{R})$

We know the Electric Field at the point $(x,y)$ will given by:

$$\vec{E}=\frac{kQ}{|\vec{R}|^2}\frac{\vec{R}}{|\vec{R}|}$$

And so:

$$\vec{E} \cdot \hat{n}=\frac{kQ}{|\vec{R}|^2}\Big(\frac{\vec{R}}{|\vec{R}|} \cdot \hat{n}\Big)=\frac{kQ}{|\vec{R}|^2}\cos(\theta)=\frac{kQ}{|\vec{R}|^2}\frac{2}{|\vec{R}|}=\frac{2kQ}{(x^2+y^2+2^2)^{3/2}}$$

From there we find the value of flux through the surface to be:

$$\Phi_E=\int_{-4}^4 \int_{-4}^4 \frac{2kQ}{(x^2+y^2+2^2)^{3/2}} dxdy$$