# Flux through faces of cube if charge is placed at an edge-center

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

The charge at edgecenter will be shared by 4 cubes so each cube will get $q/4\epsilon$ . The adjacent faces of the edge ( where the charge is located ) will have $0$ flux through them as no Electric-field-line will cross through it.  So only $4$ faces will share the flux and it'll be $q/16\epsilon$.

But I think the flux through each $4$ faces will be different and of $3$ types with $2$ being equal. I was wondering if we could do this with solid-angles but I don't know anything about it other than the image/concept of it.

Comment: 4 faces : 2 faces parallel to the edge each one with flux $\:\Phi_1$ and 2 faces normal to the edge each one with flux $\:\Phi_2$. So total flux $\:2\left(\Phi_1+\Phi_2\right)$. Note that $\:\Phi_1\ne\Phi_2 $.

Comment: so, *...it'll be $q/16\epsilon$...* is false.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :**

In general the flux through an oriented open or closed surface $\:\mathrm{S}\:$ due to a point charge $\:Q\:$ is
\begin{equation}
\Phi_{\mathrm{S}}=\dfrac{\Theta}{4\pi}\dfrac{Q}{\epsilon_{0}}
\tag{01}\label{01}
\end{equation}
where $\:\Theta\:$ the solid angle by which the charge $\:Q\:$ sees the surface.

For our case here make use of this **Proposition-Practical Rule** and [Figure-01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggS4i.png) both of them shown in my answer there [What is the electric field flux through the base of a cube from a point charge infinitesimally close to a vertex?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/278628/what-is-the-electric-field-flux-through-the-base-of-a-cube-from-a-point-charge-i/351672#351672), repeated here for convenience.

> **Proposition-Practical Rule :**
> Let a rectangular parallelogram with sides $\,a,b\,$ and a point $\,Q\,$ positioned at a height $\,c\,$ vertically up of one of its corners, see [Figure-01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggS4i.png). Then the solid angle $\,\Theta\,$ by which the point $\,Q\,$ "sees" the rectangular parallelogram is determined by the equation
> \begin{equation}
> \tan\Theta=\dfrac{s}{c\!\cdot\!d}=\dfrac{a\!\cdot\!b}{c\!\cdot\!\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}}
> \tag{02}\label{02}
> \end{equation}
> where $\,s=a\!\cdot\!b\,$ the area of the rectangular parallelogram and $\,d=\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}\,$ the diagonal from $\,Q\,$ to the opposite corner.

Try to prove that if $\:\Theta_1\:$ the solid angle by which your point charge sees a face parallel to the edge  and $\:\Theta_2\:$ the solid angle by which your point charge sees a face normal to the edge then
\begin{equation}
\tan\Theta_1\cdot\tan\Theta_2=1
\tag{03}\label{03}
\end{equation}

Note that according to the [Figure-Solid angles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p4QF.png) your charge sees the 4 not-adjacent faces by a solid angle $\:\Theta=\pi$, see [Figure-03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T36hT.png), while from equation \eqref{03} the solid angles $\:\Theta_1,\Theta_2\:$ are complementary
\begin{equation}
\Theta_1+\Theta_2=\dfrac{\pi}{2}
\tag{04}\label{04}
\end{equation}

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: I like your figures! How did you make them?

Comment: @Ryan Thorngren : Welcome. It's GeoGebra free software.