# Electric flux through five surfaces of cube

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gauss-law

> Consider a region in free space bounded by the surfaces of an imaginary cube having sides of length $a$ as shown in the Figure. A charge $+Q$ is placed at the centre $\mathrm O$ of the cube. $\mathrm P$ is such a point outside the cube that the line $\mathrm{OP}$ perpendicularly intersects the surface $\mathrm{ABCD}$ at $\mathrm R$ and also $\mathrm{OR}=\mathrm{RP}=a/2$. A charge $+Q$ is placed at point $\mathrm P$ also. What is the total electric flux through the five faces of the cube other than $\mathrm{ABCD}$?

[image]

My answer comes out to be $Q/\epsilon$. The solution is:

> Flux due to inner charge only through fives faces $= 5q/6\epsilon$
> Net flux due to outer charge $=0$ (Gauss's Law)
> Flux due to outer charge only through one face $= q/6\epsilon$
> Flux due to inner charge only through fives faces $=q/6\epsilon$ (what goes in must come out)
>
> $$\boxed{\text{Total flux} = \frac{5q}{6\epsilon} +\frac q{6\epsilon} =\frac q{\epsilon}}$$

**My doubt is:** Can we add the flux individually assuming no charge was present apart from charge under consideration?

Is my solution right or any improvements are required?
Is there another way using calculus to prove that flux through each surface of cube due to point charge at center is $q/6\epsilon$?

Comment: You forgot to upload the figure I think

Comment: "Flux due to inner charge only through fives faces =q/6e (what goes in must come out)"
I think you meant to put outer charge

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: **Hint** : Use symmetry. Union of two cubes (remove the common side ABCD) is a closed surface of 10 cube sides enclosing charge 2Q. Take the half for your answer.

Comment: Related : **(1)** [Flux through side of a cube](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/77120/flux-through-side-of-a-cube/367573#367573). **(2)** [What is the electric field flux through the base of a cube from a point charge infinitesimally close to a vertex?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/278628/what-is-the-electric-field-flux-through-the-base-of-a-cube-from-a-point-charge-i/351672#351672).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :**

Use symmetry as shown in Figure-01. Union of two cubes (remove the common side ABCD) is a closed surface (right parallelepiped) of 10 cube sides enclosing charge $\,2Q$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks , it get the flux easily as q/ϵ.

Comment: @Rishi Shekher : Welcome, Rishi.