# Electric flux due to a point charge through an infinite plane using Gauss divergence theorem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, coordinate-systems, gauss-law, vector-fields

I'm learning the basics of vector calculus when I came across this problem:

> A point charge +q is located at the origin of the coordinate system. Calculate the flux of the electric field due to this charge through the plane $z = +z_0$ by explicitly evaluating the surface integral. Convert the open surface integral into a closed one by adding a suitable surface(s) and then obtain the result using Gauss' divergence theorem.

I have no problem in solving the first part (i.e) by direct integration of the surface integral. I got the answer as $q/2\epsilon_0$, which I know is the correct answer as it can also be obtained using the solid angle formula.

But the problem is when I proceed to calculate the divergence of the electic field and then do the volume integral I run into an undefined answer. I converted the open surface into a closed volume by adding another plane at $z = -z_0$.

I'm attaching my work below:

[image]
[image]

Can someone help me out on where I made a mistake?

Comment: 1. You need a closed volume, not just 2 separate surfaces. 2. For a point charge the charge density may be expressed as a Dirac delta function, you know that this density is connected to the divergence of the electric field.

Comment: Regarding point 1, what I think is that since I'm placing two "infinitely" long planes the surface can be considered as closed one. And regarding point 2, I don't know what Dirac delta function is and how to associate it with the divergence of electric field.

Comment: The divergence of the electric field of a point charge should be zero everywhere except the location of the charge.  I suspect your problem comes from how you calculated $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bl}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}} 
\newcommand{\e}{\bl=}
\newcommand{\p}{\bl+}
\newcommand{\m}{\bl-}
\newcommand{\tl}[1]{\tag{#1}\label{#1}}
\newcommand{\hebl}{\bl{=\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!=}}$

**Hint 1 :**

In empty space the electric flux $\:\Phi_\texttt S\:$ through an **oriented**  smooth surface $\,\texttt S\,$ (open or closed) produced by a electric point charge $\,q\,$ is
\begin{equation}
\Phi_\texttt S\e \dfrac{\Theta}{\:4\pi\:}\dfrac{\:q\:}{\epsilon_0}
\tl{01}
\end{equation}
where $\,\Theta\,$ the solid angle by which the point charge $\,q\,$ $''$sees$''$ the oriented smooth surface. The term $''$oriented$''$ means that we must define at every point on the surface the unit vector $\,\mathbf n\,$ normal to it free of singularities due to the smoothness of the surface.

In cases, like the present one, that we can determine easily the solid angle $\,\Theta\,$ it's not necessary to integrate. So, try to determine by which solid angle the electric point charge $\,q\,$  $''$sees$''$ the infinite plane $\,\texttt P_{\p} \,$ at $\,z_0$<sup>(1)</sup>. Note that the orientation of this plane is determined by the unit normal vector $\,\mathbf{\hat{z}}\,$ of the positive $\,z\m$axis. Because of symmetry we have an equal electric flux through the infinite plane $\,\texttt P_{\m} \,$  located at $\,\m z_0\,$ and oriented by the unit normal vector $\,\m\mathbf{\hat{z}}\,$ of the negative $\,z\m$axis.

---

<sup>(1)
See the Figure titled $''$Solid Angles$''$ in my answer here : [Flux through side of a cube](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/77120/flux-through-side-of-a-cube/367573#367573).</sup>

$\hebl$

**Hint 2 :**

[image]

Apply Gauss Law for the cylinder of height $\,h\e 2z_0\,$ and radius $\,\rho\,$ as in the Figure and take the limit $\,\rho\bl\rightarrow\bl\infty$.

Comment: I do know that integration here is unnecessary, But the question given here is to find the answer through surface integration and then by volume integration and to verify the Gauss divergence theorem.

Comment: Thank you so much!! The cylinder idea worked out so well.

Comment: Where 4pi comes from, and also angle? Could you please show the derivation? I clearly can't find out the equation anywhere. Or just give me a reference

Comment: @Billy Istiak : I apologize, but I can't give an explanation in comments. If possible, I'll append in the future an  addendum here to give the details. I'll inform you about this with a comment-message.

Answer (score 1):

The error in your original derivation is that
$$
\frac{\partial (\sin \theta)}{\partial r} = 0,
$$
and so $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} = 0$ as well.  (Except when $r = 0$, but that's another story.)  A partial derivative implies that the other two coordinates ($\theta$ and $\phi$) are held constant.  By looking at the derivative when $r$ is constrained to the surface (which is basically what you did when you substituted $\sin \theta = \sqrt{r^2 - z_0^2}/r$), you are no longer holding $\theta$ constant.

Comment: Oh yeah! Thank you for pointing this out. I really had this doubt, but couldn't accept the fact that the divergence of the electric field will be zero in this case.  I now understood the fact that the volume integral won't give the answer since placing 2 infinite planes doesn't make the surface a closed one( I got confused by the analogy in optics where people generally say parallel rays meet at infinity).